# Adjunct of duration

Tags: adjuncts, time-reference, for

> I was running for one hour and a half.

This sentence is said to be grammatically correct on a grammar book written by non native speakers.  But I can not think of a circumstance that the sentence can fit in.

Could you help me come up with one？

Comment: It would apply if I was running a long foot race.

Comment: Thanks,  I get it.

Comment: "My favourite form of exercise is running. I was running for an hour and a half this morning." NB _an hour_ is more idiomatic than _one hour_ in this context.

Comment: "I broke my record. I was running for an hour and a half." To talk about how long you were running is pretty common among people who run for exercise or are training to run a marathon.